# Using scikit learn for Neural Networks vs Tensorflow in training

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn

I was implementing some sample Neural networks and in most tutorials saw this statement.

> Neural networks tend to work better on GPUs than on CPU. 
>   The scikit-learn framework isn’t built for GPU optimization.

So does this statement (work better) refers solely regarding the train phase of a neural network or it includes the prediction part also. Would greatly appreciate some explanation on this.

Comment: This only talks about performance/speed and includes prediction, although the difference is usually smaller and as always it's dependent on a lot of parameters (single-pred vs. batch-pred; NN size and co).

Answer (score 1):

That statement refers to the training phase. The only issue here is that you can explore the search space of feasible models in a more efficient way using a GPU so you will probably find better models in less time. However, this is only related to computational costs and not to model predictive performance.